# passing parameters to running silverlight application

Tags: javascript, silverlight, interaction

The scenario is I have a list of items in HTML; when I click on an item I use JS to dynamically create the HTML to load a silverlight app passing in the specific item # (using initParams); and my silverlight app visualizes this in a nice way.  I do this on the same page rather than loading a new webpage, and the transition is smooth.

I know it is possible to have silverlight call a JS function on my page (opposite to what I need).  I'm thinking it is also possible for my JS function to raise an event/call a method in silverlight, but not exactly sure how - has anyone tried this?    While a workaround would be to recreate the silverlight app each time, just raising an event in existing, loaded SL app would would be the perfect solution to my problem.

regards
  ewart.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a method in your Silverlight application from JavaScript.
See this [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/matt/combining-silverlight-and-javascript)

You just need to create a class in your silverlight app that registers itself as callable from JS:

```
[ScriptableType]
public partial class SomeClass
{
    private bool mouseHeldDown = false;
    private Point moveMeOffset = new Point();

    public SomeClass()
    {
        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("SilverlightObject", this);
    }


    [ScriptableMember]
    public void DoThing(int x)
    {
      //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Then you can call this from JS

```
document.getElementById("mySilverlightControl").content.SilverlightObject.DoThing(5);
```